# Change View in UIScrollView with NSTimer

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, nstimer

I am using the following code in order to create a `UIScrollView`:

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {

    CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
    [scroll addSubview:awesomeView];

}

scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);

[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

The Question is: How do I implement an `NSTimer` in order to change the page every 4 seconds?

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateCounter:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

I am struggling to write the updateCounter method. Please help

```
- (void)updateCounter:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
 NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;
     int i = 0; i++;
     if (i < numberOfViews) {

    yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    [scroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,      self.view.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
}

return; }
```

OK, so with this code, `NSTimer` changes from *view 1* to *view 2*, but it stops, it does not change after the next 4 seconds to *view 3*. What I want to do is to change from *view 1*, to *view* 2, after 4 seconds, then to *view 3*, after 4 seconds, and so on. I want to have as many views as I need.

Comment: I think its because you reinitialize i (i=0) every time updateCounter is called.  Try making the counter an instance variable and reset it/count down when i exceeds the number of pages.

Comment: Oops, you shouldn't have a loop inside updateCount.  The timer firing off every 4 seconds is kind of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing everything right. Now you need to implement `updateCounter` so that the scroll of the scrollView happens automatically. maintain global width counter. Keep updating this counter in every call to `updateCounter`. You could do this like so -

```
int global_width  = self.view.frame.size.width;
int global_height = self.view.frame.size.height;
- (void) updateCounter
{
    int width = (global_width%self.view.frame.size.width)*self.view.frame.size.width;
    [yourScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, global_height) animated:YES];

    global_width  += self.view.frame.size.width;
    return;
}
```

This way you keep cycling between the pages automatically. Hoep this works, all of it is typed freehand. But the concept is correct.

Comment: Ok, so I modified my question. AS you can see in the last part, I changed the updateCounter method and it changes from view 1 to view 2, but then it stops, how can i change to view 3 after the next 4 seconds? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a counter every four seconds, call your updateCounter method this way:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(updateCounter)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

There's two differences in what you did.  #1, the time interval is 4 seconds.  #2, if you don't have any parameters going into the updateCounter method, don't append a colon to the selector.

And then your updateCounter method:

```
- (void) updateCounter
{
    // what view are you modifying?
    // the content view or a subview within the ScrollView's contentView ?   
}
```

Comment: I currently have 3 views, therefore, I want to change each view with the updateCounter. Therefore, if I add the following in the updateCounter method: static int count = 0; count ++; switch (count & 3) { case 1: break; case 2: break; case 3:break; }} I want to add in each case an image and sound. The question then is: How do I write that in each case I want the counter to update the current view, of each of my 3 views.